# Substring in C (what will happen to the remaining in array)

Tags: c, arrays

I have given a task to generate a sub string for the given input in C. The code as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[1000];
    char *sub;
    int startFrom = 0;
    int endAt = 0;

    printf("Enter the String: ");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("Start From? ");
    scanf("%d", &startFrom);
    printf("End At? ");
    scanf("%d", &endAt);

    sub = &a[startFrom];
    a[endAt] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", sub);
    return 0;
}
```

The code however works fine, but what will happen to the rest of the characters in the array?

Comment: They're still there, less the one you overwrote with that terminator (assuming your input was sane).

Comment: use scanf("%999s",a); or fgets(a,100,stdin); never use scanf %s without a limit.

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the array remains the same; it's just that you changed one of the characters in the array to null('\0'). So if you try to access any other character after (or before) the `a[endAt]` character, you would be able to do so.

Check it out  [Your code with some extra at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7WcpRB).

However as you can see, when you try to print the original array, it would be printed only till the first '\0' character.